# Running specific tests using gradle over multiple browsers

Tags: gradle, automated-tests, spock, geb

I'm using Geb/Spock for automated testing. I'm using Gradle as my build tool.

I'd like to call different gradle tasks to build and run a specific spec(test) or a suite of specs.

I dont know enough about the gradle build lifecycle to completely understand what is going on here: https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle/blob/master/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "idea"
    id "groovy"
    id "com.energizedwork.webdriver-binaries" version "1.4"
    id "com.energizedwork.idea-base" version "1.4"
}

ext {
    // The drivers we want to use
    drivers = ["firefox", "chrome", "chromeHeadless"]

    ext {
        groovyVersion = '2.4.12'
        gebVersion = '2.2'
        seleniumVersion = '3.6.0'
        chromeDriverVersion = '2.32'
        geckoDriverVersion = '0.18.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // If using Spock, need to depend on geb-spock
    testCompile "org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
    testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
    }
    testCompile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:$groovyVersion"

    // If using JUnit, need to depend on geb-junit (3 or 4)
    testCompile "org.gebish:geb-junit4:$gebVersion"

    // Drivers
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"
}

webdriverBinaries {
    chromedriver chromeDriverVersion
    geckodriver geckoDriverVersion
}

drivers.each { driver ->
    task "${driver}Test"(type: Test) {
        group JavaBasePlugin.VERIFICATION_GROUP

        outputs.upToDateWhen { false }  // Always run tests

        systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("geb/$name")
        systemProperty "geb.env", driver
    }
}

test {
    dependsOn drivers.collect { tasks["${it}Test"] }
    enabled = false
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxHeapSize = "1g"
    jvmArgs '-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m'
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    groovyOptions.forkOptions.memoryMaximumSize = '256m'
}
```

I've tried inserting the following into build.gradle:

```
task dataGen {
    include '**com.company.project.spec.util/DataGenerationUtilSpec.groovy'
}

task sanity {
    include '**com.company.project.spec.sanity.*'
}
```

But calling these tasks (`gradle sanity`) results in a build failure:

```
Could not find method include() for arguments [**com.company.project.spec.util/DataGenerationUtilSpec.groovy] on task ':dataGen' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
```

Obviously there's existing build instructions since I can call `gradle build` and all the specs run on Chrome, I'm just not sure how to add more tasks

Comment: Can you better explain the title of this questions? Do you mean run different cases (sanity, regression, etc) or run on different browsers (chrome, firefox)

Comment: @Royg I think i can pass in which browser id like to use as a runtime argument, but I need the test to run a specific set of cases

Comment: for that usage you can use the answer below.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve Doug Clark - your question title mentions running tests in multiple browsers but your question text seems to be about running a subset of tests as part of different test tasks. It is also unclear what your setup is because from one of your comments under ToYonos' answer you seem to have no tests whatsoever - you're getting `Skipping task ':patientGen' as it has no source files`. You will need to do better at showing us the full picture if you want us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spock annotation to control the test or the Spec, see example [here](https://github.com/roygrssmn/spock-annotations).

You will have to define annotation classes and define the Spock config file to use that annotation. You then annotate the specific Specification (or test).
Now you will have to define the Spock config file in the task or from a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I think these 2 tasks are `test` tasks so it should look like that :

```
task dataGen (type: Test) {
    include '**com.company.project.spec.util/DataGenerationUtilSpec.groovy'
}

task sanity (type: Test) {
    include '**com.company.project.spec.sanity.*' 
}
```

Comment: thanks, one step closer.
Now when i call 'gradle sanity -i' I get this:
> Task :patientGen NO-SOURCE
Skipping task ':patientGen' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
:patientGen (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.

Comment: The console says all the tasks that were actionable were run, but the webdriver never kicks off

Comment: It's another issue...  `patientGen` task is not mentioned in your question

Comment: that was careless post sanitizing, dataGen and patientGen are the same